# A better method to iterate over an array and object attributes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, refactoring

(Edit:Now i just use ChatGPT for coding stuff... 1000x better than SO policy and moderators)

I found a solution that works, but i did some heavy copy/paste of blocks and there is only the params of the instance which changes (myobject.red, myobject.blue, myobject.yellow ). I try to refactor this method. There is an instance of Myobject, I need to push data in each parameter. I think it exist an elegant solution somewhere.

To create a set of data, i iterate over an array. Each result of the array needs to be pushed in the corresponding parameter of the instance.  Thanks

```
class Myobject
 def initialize
  @blue = blue
  @red = red
  @yellow = yellow
 end
end

def mymethod
  param = ['foo','bar','jaa']
  
  param.each { |param|
    case param
    when 'foo'
      data = collect_method
      myobject.blue.push(data)
    when 'bar'
      data = collect_method
      myobject.red.push(data)
    when 'jaa'
      data = collect_method
      myobject.yellow.push(data)
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: can you share the contents of "block of code" so we can see if there is common code shared between the different cases, or if it's totally different

Comment: "Block of code" are totally identical, i will correct it.

Comment: then you can pull "block of code" outside (before) the case statement, it doesn't need to be repeated if it's identical in each case

Comment: oh, "block of code" disappeared in your edit

Comment: sorry, i don't know if it add value or blur the understanding of the problem. So i put 3 identical methods

Comment: is collect_method dependent on the value of param?

Comment: Yes! for example, it create an URL to be fetched

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```rb
def mymethod
  params = {'foo'=>:blue,'bar'=>:red,'jaa'=>:yellow}
  
  params.each do |k,v|
    my_object.send(v).push(collect_method(k))
  end
end
```

where collect_method is another method in Myobject class

Comment: Clever! Thanks for the discovery of the #send method

Comment: There is no need to use `send` here. `public_send` is enough. Using `send` is confusing.

Comment: @JörgWMittag yes, `public_send` is probably better practice if you're not accessing private/protected methods. In this example it makes no substantive diff.